# Validate keycloak expiry taking in timezone differences between browser and server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, timezone, jwt, keycloak

I'm using keycloak and reactJS , while validating the token expiry time I'm trying to compare the time using the following code.

```
var expiresin =  extractedTokentst.exp;
var currentTime  = new moment(new Date()).unix();

if(+currentTime > +expiresin){
      console.log("token expired");
}
```

my server time is behind browser time by 3 mins, server time (09:57:06)  and local time or browser time (10:01:00). This is causing a problem with the token expiry time, let's say 2 mins, and additionally I will always get a time difference of 3 mins.

expiry time:  1540787715
current time:  1540787822  !!!!!!!!!
should not happen.

Comment: The [RFC7519](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7519#section-4.1.4) allows you to define a small leeway. 3 mins look acceptable right?

Comment: @FlorentMorselli since it an optional its not being considered/implemented by keycloak right?  3 mins is an example there could be more also, considering the time zone difference where the server auth server time zone and the browser time zone. It could be more also. looks like some fundamental missing? correct me if im wrong.

Comment: You are right, this feature may not be implemented by all token providers/audiences.Normally timezone/daylight saving differences do not affect the value as it represents the UNIX timestamp.

Comment: With Angular, we have the same problem. Did you solve it? This seems important and a bug @ShashankS